# What was the first PC/computer to have sound recording & playback support?

Tags: sound, windows

Sound playback and recording became mainstream on computers today, the most known introduction was around 1989-1991 with the release of windows 3.0 with Multimedia Extensions. However, what was the first computer to introduce this functionality?

Comment: Playback and recording.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of a very crude sound recording program for the Apple 2 (it may have appeared in Call-A.P.P.L.E. magazine or similar). It was certainly not "built in" functionality, it was highly experimental. But what is your threshold for inclusion?

Comment: As built-in funcionality.

Comment: It wasn't build in with a PC, as of 1989, sound wasn't available on most boards, but had to be added using a sound card.

Comment: Also, sound cards (such as [Sound Blaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_Blaster#First_generation_Sound_Blasters,_8-bit_ISA_&_MCA_cards), 1989) with this functionality worked fine in DOS before any Windows "Multimedia Extensions" (1990).

Comment: @GregHewgill It was quite easy done by using the cassette input. In fact, one of my very first programs on my brand new Apple II was reading from cassette input (playing Queen) and outputting via the internal speaker :)) And yes, it was quite crude - and surprising well at the same time.

Comment: Voice synthesis, which is not playback, goes all the way back to the vacuum tube era.  This youtube clip shows an IBM 704 singing Daisy Bell.  It's in the middle of the clip. https://youtu.be/TXK_cE9AqAI

Comment: @GregHewgill: I think I got code for capturing audio from the Apple II cassette port from either Creative Computing or Byte--probably the former, since I subscribed to that and only got Byte occasionally.

Comment: @Raffzahn Did the same with the TRS-80 Color Computer.  Whatever was playing on the cassette during e.g. a `CLOAD` was routed to the TV's speaker.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Was it routed analogue to TV-Out, or digitized inbetween as I did with the apple?

Comment: @Raffzahn All analog.  The only ADC the CoCo had was for the joysticks.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Err, and how did it read cassette tapes?

Comment: @Raffzahn I presume you're asking how it read data off cassette.  IIRC the CoCo using FSK using either of two pure (single-frequency) tones to encode data.  The reading circuit used zero-crossing detection and the computer used the timing between crossings to differentiate a zero from a one.  So yes, technically a second ADC but a very crude one, only capable of measuring pure tones.  IIRC, the joysticks were measuring by timing capacitor decay.  The chip that handled all this was the SC77526 6-bit ADC/DAC.

Comment: @AlexHajnal My original comment about the Apple II was about detecting a signal change at the cassette in, by software, to toggle the speaker as output. So it was a digitalisation. Now, if the CoCo has a direct connection (not going thru the CPU) of cassette in and TV sound, then I'd see it as a different case, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, totally different.  Did use it for playing music though :^)  I'm super-curious now to see how well the CoCo's zero-crossing detector would work as a general-purpose audio ADC.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Shouldn't be that bad (as said, was surprised about being able to listen to via the apple speaker) - but you might need a direct controlled speaker output. Going thru a sound chip may not work as great.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: According to an article I read in the 1980s, the CoCo has an analog comparator that compares the input signal from the cassette to a signal produced by the audio output DAC.  As a consequence, it is possible to write a program to behave as a crude successive approximation DAC, and it would probably also have been possible to write a program to behave as a one-bit ADPCM codec.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: Thinking about it, I don't think the comparator was on the cassette input, but rather the joystick inputs.  Unlike many computers that used an RC circuit to measure controller resistance, the CoCo joysticks were voltage dividers, a combination of a DAC and comparator were used to read them, and they were consequently capable of sampling at audio rates when programmed suitably.

Comment: @supercat Yea, I was looking at the CoCo schematics and service manual and only the joysticks and the DAC feed into the analog comparator. To read the joysticks, binary search is used by setting the DAC to various values and checking the comparator output to zero-in on the joystick's value. Since the DAC is also used for audio output, sound output should be turned off before reading the joysticks.  BTW, I found the article you mentioned, quite an interesting read.  Will post another comment summarizing it shortly(ish).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> However, what was the first computer to introduce this functionality?

Recording and playback has been always there - at least for micros.

Early S100 systems are a great example for example by using Cromemco's D+7A board of 1977, or Ithaca Audio's 8 chanel ADDA card of 1981 (AFAIR even MITS offered a suitable board in 1977) and sufficient storage.

Heck, there was even software to record and playback sound using an unexpanded Apple II. Ok, maybe not great, but quite functional.

The main issue for sound recording and playback is the availability of large RAM portions for buffering (I'd say anything above 16 KiB) and mass storage fast enough to store or retrive data fast enough. While floppies could deliver the needed transfer speed, their capacity was rather limited. So the critical point for availability can be set in 1980 with the introduction of Seagates ST-506 hard disk.

---

Now, a complete different issue might be when sound recording and playback became a mainstream commodity. This is way more related to system software able to mange sound streams. Apples Mac series was for example beginning with the very first 128k Mac capable to produce a continuous background sound stream. The hardware integrated Sound DMA it as part of the video timing. And it wasn't long that sound input hardware was as well available by third party (*1) and well supported by OS extensions. So it's safe to set a date around 1984/85 here.

---

*1 - Apple didn't supply any sound input hardware at all until the LC series, and no high quality until the Quadra 840 AV in 1993. This was due a settlement with the Beatles' [Apple Corp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Corps#Apple_Corps_v._Apple_Computer), which prevented Apple Inc. of going into 'musik business'.

Comment: after seeing audio digitized and played back on an Apple //e, I did some experimental code on my C64 at home and was able to get a few playable seconds of That's Pep! by DEVO.  -  of course the quality sucked, but it was pretty neat at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, for some definitions of computer:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSALY 1943

This was a speech encryption system that did all the things a modern computer would do when recording and playing back sound, except storing it...:

-Encode analog sound as quantized digital samples (albeit some analog pre-processing happened to conserve bandwith).

-Process the resulting data digitally (not by a programmed CPU though, more of a hardwired - but digital - set of circuits).

-Reconstitute an analog signal on the receiving end from the digital samples eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having seen youtube videos on UNIX belonging to 1960s/1970s where the promotion videos of that time had playback support.

Comment: Your answer would be improved with a bit more detail. Can you link to some of these videos and describe them a little bit? What machines were these and what kind of video were they playing?

Answer (score -1):

This depends on what quality you want (e.g. music and speech or something more crude) and whether you want this to be intended functionality or some by-product.

For instance, any computer with magnetic tape storage could use the tape recorder's microphone as a kind of input device. For instance, I remember using the recorder's microphone for controlling BK-0010 with hand slaps or loud shouts. Of course, this functionality was never intended, but since analog input was mapped to an input registry, a program could do whatever it wanted with it.